# InitializeComponent not found in WP8.1 Silverlight Xamarin Shared Project

Tags: c#, silverlight, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently working on getting our project up and running on WP8.1 but I'm getting thousands of errors regarding just about everything being wrong in the project.

The main issues are missing dependencies which slowly but surely are being re-added (though they are in a lot of cases with Azure completely different then what iOS and Android use which is really annoying) and none of the XAML pages work (and we use a lot of those).

With the XAML pages not working the method InitializeComponent() is just not available and I can't find anything useful online on how to get this back again, I've got the latest version of Xamarin Forms installed and it should just work but doesn't want to :(

Our project is a Shared Project, we have a Shared Project, the iOS project, the Android Project and now also the Windows Phone Project.

The error I'm getting on one of the xaml pages is,

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0103  The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context    PD.WinPhone C:\Projects\PD-xamarin\PD\PD\Views\Controls\Prizes\PrizeView.xaml.cs    87  Active
```

This class extends the ViewCell class and works without any issue on iOS and Android, it's just Windows Phone that doesn't work, how can we get this to work as it should?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, Xamarin.Forms 2.1.X (latest version) and the Windows Phone project is an 8.1 SilverLight project

Comment: Have been running into this since upgrading to VS 2015 and Xamarin 4/XF 2 also. Set the errors view in VS 2015 to Build only (instead of Build and Intellisense) helped reduce the noise. Xamarin Forums has discussion about this too https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17638/initializecomponent-does-not-exist. Android and iOS apps still build and run, so it is not a showstopper.

Comment: I've already seen that post but it's focussed on iOS and Xamarin Studio on Mac, that works without any problem for us, it's the Windows Phone version on Visual Studio 2015 that's not working. Setting the error log to Build only didn't really change much, it's still showing all the errors of all .xaml.cs files where it can't find the view items defined in the .xaml file

Comment: Ok so there was a fault in the link between two .xaml and .xaml.cs files which caused it to still fail. After re-trying the Build Only error reporting with the link fixed it actually tried to build for the device! Unfortunately the SQLite library for WP8 didn't want to cooperate but at least we're a step farther.